# WatchKit get user's preferred handedness

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit, watchos-4

I read that in WatchOS 4 developers would be able to access which hand the user had set up their Apple Watch for (as in left/right). I haven't been able to find any documentation on this. Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually available since `watchOS 3.0` using `WKInterfaceDevice.current().wristLocation`.

For more information, see the documentation of [wristLocation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice/1650810-wristlocation).